# How to write client and server codes seperate in a playN project?

Tags: java, gwt, client-server, playn

The normal GWT projects have client code and server code. I want to write separate client and server code in same playN project. When I compile my current project I get errors like, *couldn't find module,  java.lang.Thread*, as it is not supported by GWT client code. For my project I need lot of server code to be added and I need full Java packages.

And the main problem is, I have my own library with full of server side code, and when I add the library, I get this problem.

How can I separate the client code and server code such a way that it won't give me an error like mentioned above? If we can separate client and server code, is there a way to add the library only for server side code?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know PlayN, but in GWT you define which path are to be compiled for client side using

```
<source path='client' />
```

inside your .gwt.xml file. Other path under the module file folder are compiled as server side code.

In order to understand your problem more completely, I git-cloned the play sample [showcase](http://code.google.com/p/playn/wiki/GettingStarted), then I took a look on the file hierarchy (the GWT part is detailed by the way).

```
showcase/
   android/
      ...
   core/
      ...
   flash/
      ...
   html/
      src/
         main/
            java/
               playn/
                  showcase/
                     html/
                        ShowcaseHtml.java
                     Showcase.gwt.xml
            webapp/
               WEB-INF/
                  web.xml
               Showcase.html
      pom.xml
   ios/
     ...
   java/
     ...
   build.xml
   pom.xml
```

As we can see we have *html/src/main/java/playn/showcase/**Showcase.gwt.xml*** side by side with 
*html/src/main/java/playn/showcase/**html*** folder.

Here is Showcase.gwt.xml content:

```
<module rename-to='showcase'>
  <inherits name='playn.PlayN'/>
  <!-- for the peas sample -->
  <inherits name="org.jbox2d.GwtBox2D" />
  <!-- for the menu UI -->
  <inherits name='tripleplay.TriplePlay'/>
  <!-- for enhanced logging -->
  <inherits name="playn.logging.Enhanced" />

  <source path='core'/>
  <source path='html'/>

  <public path="resources" />

  <entry-point class='playn.showcase.html.ShowcaseHtml'/>
</module>
```

So as for my experience if there exists a *html/src/main/java/playn/showcase/**server*** folder with code in it, and no reference made to this code from *other code*, it must be avoided by GWT compiler. Then with maven it could be compile if declared appriately.

Comment: Hi, in playN also in the HTML version of the project, we have gwt.xml file.  what we are doing is add all the diffrent package root folder path as <source path='foldername' />.                                      like,      <source path="core" />
    <source path="html" />
    <source path="rules" />
    <source path="view" />
    <source path="util" />

Comment: for a single playN project u will have projects like projectName, projectName-core,  projectName-android, projectName-java, projectName-html.   We will have this projectName.gwt.xml in html version.

Comment: ok, as I understand it you have projectName-html/ folder containing a projectName.gwt.xml with <source path="core" /> <source path="html" /> <source path="rules" /> <source path="view" /> <source path="util" /> directive. What happen if you create a folder server in projectName-html/ and put server side code in it ? (without adding any <source path="server" /> at all)

Comment: ok. Let me try that. So you mean it is all about which folder you are creating the class? the code in client folder will be converted to js and the code in server folder will run as java server side code?

Comment: And The errors are from the server side code library which I have inherited in the gwt.xml file. How can i specify it only to server side? in the library I am using java.lang.Thread

Comment: between I forgot to tell you, The html folder has no code, other than an entry point to the core project. But I think I can make folders in core and do the same right?

Comment: The basic work of GWT is to convert class that are into folders designated with <source path='foldername' /> into JS. But it has restriction about class of the JRE (http://code.google.com/intl/fr-FR/webtoolkit/doc/latest/RefJreEmulation.html).
java.lang.Thread is not supported because as for now it's not translatable into JS. Other folders are not compiled by GWT but by a plain javac you must configure to generate a server side code (for eg: into WEB-INF/classes/<package>/<classname>.class) and bundle in a war file. This is done by the GWT plugin of eclipse and maven gwt plugin too.

Comment: Hi, I understand this. Can you explain how exactly I can configure the server side code to be compiled by normal javac? my project compiles all my code and included library the other way and shows error for unsupported features of java.